# can't make rails assets pipeline to works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

i am developing an app in rails with some css and js plugins template,
by default we should separate or js and css file into javascript and css folder right?

but the problem is my plugins folder structure are quite complex,
have a lot of sub folders, so i decided to put all the assets (css, js, images, fonts) into a folder, the problem is everything not working on production mode, the css styles, scripts, images all not loaded, please help.

here is my structure :

```
javascripts
stylesheets
public_assets
  - img
    - icon
    - bg
    - favicon
    - images
      - proteam
    - png
      - ualanding
    - portofolio
      - fullsize
      - thumbnail
  - font
  - css
  - js
  - sass
  - vendor
    - ninja-slider
    - bootstrap
      - font
      - css
      - js
    - font awesome 
      - css
      - fonts
      - less
      - scss
    - jquery
    - magnific-popup
    - scroolreveal
  - vid
images
Static_Dev
```

FYI i already run

> rake assets:precompile

command

i reference my images mostly like these :

> `<img alt="UrbanAce" src="assets/img/logo.png" height="24">`

i believe when i run on production mode, the assets path changed, so i changed my image tag to :

> `<%= image_tag "logo.png", { src: "logo.png", height: "24"} %>`

the above code did not work, even in development mode.

also, what if i need to call some background images from css?
something like :

```
 .hero {
  background-image: url("../img/png/UA-Landing/UA-Pattern.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 76px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

i call font like this :

```
@font-face{font-family:FreightSansPro;src:url(../font/FreightSansPro-Light.otf) format("opentype");
```

how should i replace it? so it will work on production and development mode.

many thanks....

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png", { src: "logo.png", height: "24"} %>
```

you don't need to set `src`. The first argument is a filename already. Do this instead:

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png", height: "24" %>
```

If there is a file at `app/assets/images/logo.png`, it will display.

To address another file (say, favicon), use path like this:

```
<%= image_tag "img/favicon.ico" %>
```

It's a path to the file, minus the top level folder (`public_assets` in this example).

Comment: hello, i tried your solution, <%= image_tag "img/logo.png" %> still not working, image missing on production mode, but its working on development.

Comment: do i need to config something in environment or application rb?

Comment: What is the src of that image that you get on production?

Comment: something like src="/assets/img/logo-1ce59ff71a9b947be591324300ccb9472e958b086b26e39e1123d96c4f95a08b.png" i checked under public/img folder and i can find an image with that name. somehow its now working from image tag?